# Why does my version of Blender not include MPEG as an output format for animations?

Tags: rendering, animation, video

I recently started working in Blender through the latest Fedora distribution of Linux and completed my first project. When I went to render my animation and select the file format for the video, the only three Video file formats listed were AVI Raw, AVI Jpeg, and Frame Server. I want to render my animation as an MPEG, but am not currently able to. Please help.

Comment: Which version of blender you are using?

Comment: Also note that it is standard to render an animation as a series of single images and then compile them into a video file later. Rendering directly to a video file can cause major issues.

Comment: I am using version 2.74

Comment: It should be there, I have seven options under movie. What OS are you running on?

Comment: mmh, also using CentOs (rhel) here and I get this selection: http://i.stack.imgur.com/zqwE0.png, but as @NoviceInDisguise mentioned, I would also suggest to render an image sequence and compile it afterwards.

Comment: I am using Linux version 3.19.7-200.fc21.x86_64 and running the Fedora distro

Comment: I have the same options as Poor, but I am using Windows 7. It is possible that the MPEG encoder used by Blender can not be implemented on Linux

Comment: Try downloading blender from the official website, it's possible your distro's blender package is not compiled with ffmpeg.